# Is there a way to set custom string Axis Ticks in core plot?

Tags: swift, graph, viewcontroller, core-plot

Is there a way to set the Axis Ticks to be non-numeric in CorePlot. So that it doesn't display 1,2,3,4,5.... on the axis, but rather corresponding stings A,B,C,D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create new axis labels from locations through

```
func axis(_ axis: CPTAxis, shouldUpdateAxisLabelsAtLocations locations: Set<NSNumber>) -> Bool {
var newLabels: Set<CPTAxisLabel> = []
for tickLocation in locations {
    let theLabelTextStyle: CPTTextStyle? = nil 
    let labelString = "?"
    let newLabelLayer = CPTTextLayer(text: labelString, style: theLabelTextStyle)
    let newLabel = CPTAxisLabel(contentLayer: newLabelLayer)
    newLabel.tickLocation = tickLocation
    newLabel.offset = labelOffset
    newLabel.rotation = labelRotation
    newLabels.insert(newLabel)
}
axis.axisLabels = newLabels
return false
```

}

func axisShouldRelabel(_ axis: CPTAxis) -> Bool {
return true
}

func axis(_ axis: CPTAxis, shouldUpdateMinorAxisLabelsAtLocations locations: Set) -> Bool {
return true
}